# I want to make my model to the other side

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, mirror, mirror-modifier

In the robot tutorial , ryan is working on the right side , for some reason I m working on the left side.

Is there a way to work to the right side, instead of left side, without repeating everything again ?

[image]

the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LMEUXPxl8g&list=PLsGl9GczcgBvuBDsj9dA1Aa_arhcJib-s&ab_channel=RyanKingArt
[image]

Comment: when everything is selected, try S, X, -1, Enter, Shift+N.

Comment: thank you for the reply, i went to edit mode press A to select everything type S,X -1  , enter , shift +N now the shape changed for some reason and still didnt change to the right side i will upload the blend

Comment: Ah, right, my bad, I'll write an answer and add a few more steps needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Disable Clipping** in your *Mirror Modifier*:

[image]

2. Press <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> to Change *Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor*
3. <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> to flip along $x$ axis.
4. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate Normals*

**That's it.** Future visitors might need in 1½. (between 1. and 2.) <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> (move *3D Cursor* to *World Origin*), and instead of 4. do <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> to *Flip Normals*, as Recalculating Normals is not 100% reliable (basically if your topology is weird, it may fail you).